# The Roo shell does not generate ITDs for my @RooConversionService

Tags: spring-mvc, aspectj, spring-roo

I have added the following class in my Roo app:

```
/**
 * A central place to register application converters and formatters.
 */
@RooConversionService
public class ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean extends FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean {

    @Override
    protected void installFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        super.installFormatters(registry);
    }
}
```

I have registered the class as follows in **webmvc-config.xml**:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="applicationConversionService"/>
```

and in **applicationContext.xml**:

```
<bean class="com.bignibou.converter.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean" id="applicationConversionService"/>
```

Note that I don't use JSP but Thymeleaf instead so that I have not run the "`web mvc all`" command at all and therefore I have no web Scaffolds.

**Can anyone please tell me why the ITDs for the RooConversionService are not generated??**

Comment: First, just to make sure, you do have the Roo Shell running, correct?  If it is, then you might try to simply touch the files.  I have found cases where I update files and Roo Shell seems to ignore the changes, but touching the file sort of forces it to pay attention.

Comment: Touch from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read the in the Spring Roo Docs:

> "Roo will automatically maintain an ITD with Converter registrations for every associated entity that needs to be displayed somewhere in a view" (Page 97)

This logically would mean that if you have no scaffolded views then Roo isn't governing the Conversion Service and you need to author and register these manually.